# Digital Clock - set time x hours ahead?

Tags: switches, clock

I have a digital clock made from an electronic kit - it has 3 buttons (1 to set the time, 1 to set alarm, 1 to cancel the alarm).

I want to be able to set it so every time it is connected to power it sets to 20:00 instead of 12:00 (8 hours ahead). The reason for this is I am actually creating two clocks with 2 time zones and I want to set the time on both from 1 button/switch.

I am new to electronics so forgive me if this is an easy question, but how would I go about achieving this? I assume I would be unable to change the default start time on the clock, so is it possible to send a certain amount of "button pushes" (setting the time) each time it powers up?

E.g.

1 button push = +1 minute
480 button pushes = 480 minutes = 8 hours

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/alarm-clock-kit-n21fl

This is the clock kit I have

Comment: 480 is a lot of button pushes, but yeah, it can be done, eg use a CD4060 with an and gate on the Q8,Q7,Q6 to stop it and pulse output
 on Q1

Comment: or you could get a new ATtiny and write your own firmware to start up at whatever time you like ...

Answer (score 2):

A little microcontroller can generate as many "button presses" as you want, causing the time to be set to whatever you want.  If you want to play with that, try using an arduino (because it's easy to get started) and connect an opto-isolator or reed-relay across each button on the clock.  By pulsing pins on the arduino, you can "press" the buttons on the clock.

However, "a little microcontroller" is exactly what is on that clock.  Why don't you modify the kit clock's software so that it comes on at 20:00 at reset instead of 00:00?  That would be much neater and require no additional hardware.

That chip (ATtiny2313) is an AVR, for which there are good free tools (compilers etc) available.  In fact, it is a smaller version of the chip (ATmega328P) present on the arduino.

You will probably discover than an arduino with RTC is a far more powerful, accurate and flexible clock than that kit, and cheaper.  It could trivially represent multiple timezones and show each timezone on a different display, for example.

Comment: the at-tiny 2313 is also pin-compatible with the 20-pin 8051 chips used in some kit clocks, (I mean it has the power , crystal, reset, and GPIO pins in the same places)